# How can I best log a NameValueCollection into a database field in a readable way?

Tags: c#, xml, namevaluecollection

Is there a standard way of doing this?  I had considered using XML, but perhaps there is a more straight-forward way.

To clarify, I'm dumping the whole collection in a "details" column in my database - I do parse some but want to keep an archive of the whole set.  I was able to get SoapFormatter to work fine, though this is a bit heavy.

Comment: What are your values going to be? Just text?

Comment: Just text in the values.

Comment: Isn't a DB just a glorified `NameValueCollection` anyways?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably go about this by storing the NameValue pair as a name value pair in the DB.

ie. Have a table with a Name and Value Column (Maybe a Primary Key ID if names arent unique) then foreach item in your collection you can insert a row.

Retrieving it would be as easy as selecting where the Name is whatever name you want to get the value for.

Answer (score 0):

One option is serialize your NameValueCollection and save the byte[] in the database. You can use either XML serialization or BinaryFormatter.

A Table with two columns.
FirstColumn : Key for the log
SecondColumn : Value (Serialized Log which has namevalueCollection).

**Edit:**

If the value is just text. Save that it as it is. No need to serialize or convert to xml I think. In the first column save the key and save the value in the second column.

Comment: Thanks Charith, I was actually looking for a way to store the whole collection into a field in the db as a backup.